# Measuring Quality Coupons

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models

I am trying to build a model to understand what coupons offered by the team are quality vs not (preferably with a score so coupons with a specific score can be pushed to customers for AB testing - that way quality is accounted for).

I was thinking of using a classification technique to understand all past coupon performance and also then predict what future coupons will do well.

The issue I face with a classification is that coupons are sent out to certain customers and not others, are valid for different date/times, are for various products (e.g. you may get a coupon for laundry detergent and not need it but that doesn't mean its a bad coupon) and so on. I want to make sure the model is fair to both what the customer thinks is a "good coupon" as well as what is sourced as a "good coupon".

Are there any papers or research or books / blogs/ examples on this? Is there a robust statistical method I can look into here?